# Add a new button to an existing fine-uploader instance?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm having a bit of trouble with Fine-uploader... 
I create one instance on the first page-call, attached to an invisible element as jQuery Plugin but I have different places where a button to upload can appear... These buttons/links are not existing when fine-uploader is initialized...

Can/How can I add an additional button to an existing fine-uploader instance?

Or do I need to use a workaround like having one invisible button and "forward" the click of my new buttons?

Thanks,

Milan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are dynamically rendering upload buttons *after* Fine Uploader is initialized on the page.

The answer based on your use case would be to create a file input element, style it how you want, and then pass that into `addFiles` on your instance of Fine Uploader.

---

One workaround would be to render the buttons *before* the uploader is initialized and use `extraButtons`:

```
$("#uploader").fineUploader({
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg"],
        sizeLimit: 5000000 // 5 MiB
    },
    extraButtons: [
        {
            element: $("#pdfButton"),
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ["pdf"]
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

With this you can completely customize your extra buttons with their own validation rules and other options.

Comment: Hmm I was wondering if this is still the best method.  Would be quite convenient to allow adding buttons dynamically via FineUploader.  Making it manual seems dangerous, as FineUploader also supports multiple files, folders etc.  Is there no way to do it natively still?